# Assigning values of points outside a buffer to points within a buffer

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, point, buffer, line

I have 10m buffers around line features and a point shapefile which has some points intersecting the buffer.
I would like to take each point that falls within the buffer and assign it the value of the point it is closest to outside of the buffer.

Anybody know how to accomplish this? I'm using version 10.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method would be to split your point file (via a select and export or some other method) into to new files - points within buffers and points that are not. From there you can use a [Spatial Join](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000000q000000) (which doesn't require an Advanced License if you don't have one) to join the points outside the buffers to those inside. With the settings of that tool you can limit it to joining only the closest point with a one to one join. After that you can either field calculate or export the join results to a new file to have the outside point attributes assigned to the inside points.

Comment: +1 and the spatial join (join_one_to_one, closest) will already give you the attributes that you are looking for if you select the appropriate field mapping : no need for an extra join

Comment: The spatial join method worked. I could not try the Near tool because of licensing issues. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [Near (analysis)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000001q000000) tool. The resulting table will show which point is closest by whatever OBJECTID you specify. Then perform a join and field calculate the values into your previous points.

Comment: Near requires an Advanced License to use. Also note that the points are in a single shapefile, which means the results would be to the nearest point period, whether they were in the buffer or not. As a first step you'd need to split the points to two separate files, those within buffers and those without.